# v-bind:style won't automatically update with function called by setTimeout in click handler method?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I use `v-bind:style="{backgroundColor: getColor(row, column)}"` in a group of divs for their background color.

I then have a colorChange method which will update the list indicating the color for the group of divs when it is called.

I have tried calling that colorChange method directly in the click handler method, and everything works fine, the getColor method will automatically get called and color of divs will update accordingly after that the click handler method is done.

But when I set the colorChange method to be called by `setTimeout(this.colorChange, 50);` in the click handler method, I found out the getColor method will not get called after the colorChange method is done, and color of divs won't update.

How should I make the style update?

---

UPDATE: I think I have found why it is not updating, but I still don't know how to solve the problem TAT

I just tried commenting out the call to the colorChange method in the click handler method, and found out that the v-bind:style will still update even though there is now no change to any style. So I guess what's triggering the v-bind:style to refresh is the click handler method invoked by @click, and since by setting `setTimeout(this.colorChange, 50);` instead of direct calling will cause the click handler method to end before colorChange gets called, so the style will update before colorChange is done, so there won't be any change in view.

How can I manually make style to update after colorChange method is done?

Comment: what the heck is an `X method`??? anyway, it's probably a `this` issue - try `setTimeout(() => this.colorChange(), 50);`

Comment: X method is a click handler method lol, I should have make it more clear. I have tried `setTimeout(() => this.colorChange(), 50);` , but it doesn't seem to work, it's just act the same as before, v-bind:style just won't call getColor method again to get the updated color

Comment: Is this vue2 or vue3?

Comment: I'm using v2.7.14

Answer (score 0):

Most probably is a 'this' context issue! using setTimeout pushes the function in the callback que, which is a different execution context. Try using it inside an arrow function which will get the 'this' context form the enclosing object :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).